# best way to sort by id on the index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, view, controller

I have a gossip controller and model and before i've got this way to display all my gossips in the index view :

**My controller :**

```
def index
  @gossips = Gossip.all
end
```

**My view index.html.erb :**

```
<% @gossips.each do | gossip | %>
  <div class="card gossip-card" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title"><%= gossip.title %></h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"><%= gossip.user.username %></h6>
      <%= link_to "Read", gossip_path(gossip), :class => "btn btn-info" %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_gossip_path(gossip), :class => "btn btn-success" %>
      <%= link_to "Delete", gossip_path(gossip), :class => "btn btn-danger", method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

---

But when I edit a gossip it goes all the way down to the last position, probably because they are sorted by modification date.
So i've found this solution for my controller :

```
def index
  @gossips = Gossip.all.sort_by { |gossip| gossip.id  }
end
```

I would like to know if it is normal that my gossips are normally sorted by date of modifications and if it was possible to do this more cleanly to sort them by id than what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never ever use `.all` in any controller or model or anywhere. For your use case

```
# for ascending order
def index
  @gossips = Gossip.order(:id)
end

# for descending order
def index
  @gossips = Gossip.order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

Also try to refer Rails docs for reference.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#read

Comment: "Never ever use `.all`" - could you please elaborate?

Comment: Why never use .all ?

Comment: It's not a good approach to list all the data in one request (Assuming it's not a constant set of data but increasing regularly) because it's going to increase the response times. It's always better to use pagination and can also add cache to improve response times.

Comment: What an exaggeration. There's a big difference between "`.all` doesn't suit every possible use case" and "never ever use `.all`". Moreover, this answer duplicates the already existing one.

Comment: @inmydelorean Thanks a lot for the enlightenment :D and technically it's not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want leave sorting on your database:

```rb
def index
  @gossips = Gossip.order(:id)
end
```